# Export data to google sheet with android studio : How to transfer variables between activities?

Tags: java, android, variables, export

i'm trying to apply some tutorials about posting some data on a google sheet thanks to barcode system.

The idea is easy : I want to scan a book barcode and to send the ISBN (for exemple scanContent = 0123456789012) to Google sheet.

I've almost managed to do it !
But here is a point that I can't do anything because of the lack of knowledges I have in Java (I just copied the differents tutorials)

How should I do to export my variable "scanContent" to the public class "SendRequest" ? Indeed, for the moment, the data I send to Google Sheet is "undefined"
There are many helps on Stackoverflow but I don't manage to apply them to my code...

Please help me because this problem makes me crazy ! :'( Thank you very much !!!
Here is the begining of the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    string scanContent;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        formatTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        contentTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private Button scanBtn;
    private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.scan_button) {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT : " + scanFormat);

            new SendRequest().execute();

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){}
        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try{
                URL url = new URL("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxIIKqD6ksuVd0eNCVcStIXIkvLSgjty1RqaHn96pY/dev");
                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

                contentTxt.setText("EAN : " + scanContent);
                postDataParams.put("sdata",scanContent);


                Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

. . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it properly, look into the concept of [varargs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/) and pass arguments directly into the doInBackground method.
If you want the simple way, create a constructor for the SendRequest class.
Try this:

```
new SendRequest("scanContent").execute();

public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String scanContent;
    SendRequest(String scanContent){
        this.scanContent = scanContent;
    }
}

protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    Log.d("SendRequest", scanContent);
}
```